# Create unique id for each binary section

Tags: r, unique

I have made a binary column "y/n" represented by 1 and 0 (yes and no, respecively). I now want to give each section marked 1 a unique id based on the name of the file and the position in the column.
Below is an example of what I would like it to look like. I have no preference for what 0 should be, just as long as the sections marked as 1 have a unique id.

```
> y/n         id                       
> 1                    catid_a                 
> 1                    catid_a                                      
> 1                    catid_a                 
> 0                    no_id                                     
> 1                    catid_b                                     
> 1                    catid_b                 
> 0                    no_id
```

Usually to name an id I use 
`data$id <- as.factor(substr(basename(files[i]),1,13))` 
but it doesn't work in this instance as I want to have multiple id's in a column this just gives one.. does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!
Grace

Comment: It is not clear based on the example.  Do you have a column `y/n` and want to create the 'id' based on it?

Comment: y/n represent 1 and 0 respectively, I have edited the question hope it makes more sense

Comment: I would do `letters1 <- c(letters, do.call(paste0, expand.grid(letters, letters)));

df1$id <-inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$"y/n"), {val1 <- values;
               val1[values!=0] <- paste0("catid_", letters1[seq_along(values[values!=0])]);
              val1[values==0] <- "no_id";
                values <- val1}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rle`

```
df1$id <-inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$`y/n`), {val1 <- values
               val1[values!=0] <- paste0("catid_", letters[seq_along(values[values!=0])])
              val1[values==0] <- "no_id"
                values <- val1}))
df1$id
#[1] "catid_a" "catid_a" "catid_a" "no_id"   "catid_b" "catid_b" "no_id"
```

---

Or another option is `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(`y/n`)][`y/n`==0,  id := 'no_id' ,grp
      ][is.na(id), id := paste0("catid_", letters[.GRP]), grp][, grp := NULL][]
#   y/n      id
#1:   1 catid_a
#2:   1 catid_a
#3:   1 catid_a
#4:   0   no_id
#5:   1 catid_b
#6:   1 catid_b
#7:   0   no_id
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`y/n` = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = "y/n", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea (using @akrun's dataset),

```
y <- replace(paste0('catid_', cumsum(c(1, diff(df1$`y/n`) != 0))), df1$`y/n` == 0, 'no_id')

y
#[1] "catid_1" "catid_1" "catid_1" "no_id"   "catid_3" "catid_3" "no_id"
```

To get the values to be sequential, we need to add a couple of more lines and include a package,

```
yy <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', y[grepl('[0-9]+', y)]))
y[grepl('[0-9]+', y)] <- stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(y[grepl('[0-9]+', y)], '[0-9]+', 
                                                                 cumsum(c(1, diff(yy)!=0)))

y
#[1] "catid_1" "catid_1" "catid_1" "no_id"   "catid_2" "catid_2" "no_id"
```

Comment: Your code is compact and nice. I also attempted in similar way initially but i think you are missing one clause (if I am not wrong)

Comment: @akrun thanks! Maybe I am missing the letters after `catid_` to distinguish the groups? (I have numbers instead) but that was the only way to get it as compact

Comment: What I meant was the consecutive numbers/letters for which I had gone through some pain :-)

Comment: Thanks both work in their own right. @Sotos the method you use is nice and compact but it looks like it takes into consideration the gaps as an id. note the id skips 2 and the next one is three.

Comment: Thanks @akrun your code does the job! I just wonder what letter will appear when the code reaches 27 id's as the alphabet will be completed... Appreciate the help (I've tried to upvote both answers but my rating is too low) Cheers

Comment: @GraceSutton Good question.  I tthink you can replace the `letters` with `c(letters, do.call(paste0, expand.grid(letters, letters)))` in the code.  It should be enough for 676 cases.

Comment: @GraceSutton And now it's not as compact but does the job as required :)

Comment: Thanks @akrun running that line of code alone does indeed print 676 characters however if I try and incorporate it into the code I get an error. `df1$id <-inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$`y/n`), {val1 <- values
  val1[values!=0] <-  c(letters, do.call(paste0,expand.grid(letters, letters)),paste0(id, letters[seq_along(values[values!=0])])) #this is the section that I think I have done wrong but not familiar enough with the syntax#

  val1[values==0] <- "no_id"
  values <- val1}))`

Comment: @GraceSutton  Look at the `paste0(id, letters`.  Here also you need to change it